# How to add code dinamically with JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to add some dinamically generated code to an existent HTML file that uses Jquery Mobile:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
Click on the button
    <a href="#section" id="abutton" data-role="button">Add item</a>
    <label for="id" id="id-label">ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="" />
    <label for="name" id="name-label">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
</div>
```

The problem is that when I append some code, the new code doesn't adquire the same look than the existing:

```
 $('#abutton').click(function(){
        var code = '<label for="surname" id="surname-label">Surname:</label>' +
                   '<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value="" />';
        $("#page").append(code);
        return false;
 });
```

[image]

I've been researching and I've seen that the non-dynamically generated HTML code has some added tags and classes. I suppose that I must call some function to parse the new dynamically generated code, but which? Or should I do something completely different?

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ytdkffsz/2/): I've added a dynamically generated  to show other structures that jquery mobile generate and that cannot be resolved only adding some classes.

Comment: `$("#page").append(code).enhanceWithin();`

Comment: Yes @Omar, that's the answer!! Please, put it in an answer to accept it as the good one :)

Answer (score -2):

Your missing the ui class which are adding to the label and input field initailly by jquery mobile.

But when you add new label and input field its won't get those class. so you need to add class while adding those field.

```js
 $('#abutton').click(function(){
        var code = '<label for="surname" id="surname-label" class="ui-input-text">Surname:</label>' +
              '<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value="" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" />';
        $("#page").append(code);
        return false;
 });
```

Comment: Mmmhhhh... I've tested your code and still not working :/

Comment: Working, but, is this the only way to do it? It seems too dark, because you have to know about the internals of the jquery.mobile that could change ...

Comment: And what happens if you have a <select> that has a <div> wrapper around it?